# Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax-error

I was in the middle of coding while I saw this error appear out of nowhere, I've spend hours but I can't figure it out, could someone please help me out of it.

```
package com.example.good;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplasAct extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle sidra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(sidra);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread timer=new Thread();
    {
        public void run()   //error appears here
        {
        try{
                sleep(5000);
           }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                 finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent("com.example.good.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                        }

        }

    };
    timer.start();

}
}
```

On the error definition, it says,

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
 EnumHeaderName
- Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete 
 BlockStatements
- Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
```

Comment: Formatting my friend... if you are using eclipse, use .. "ctrl+a" then "ctrl+shift+f" . Also, remove the semicolon (;) after "new Thread()"

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing an anonymous class here:

```
Thread timer=new Thread();{
```

So you need to remove the semicolon

```
Thread timer=new Thread() {
```

Semicolon terminates an executable statement. So your class implementation remains unhooked and causing compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `;` from `Thread timer=new Thread();`

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.good;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplasAct extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle sidra) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(sidra);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread timer=new Thread()
    {
        public void run()   //error appears here
        {
        try{
                sleep(5000);
           }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                 finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent("com.example.good.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
                        }

        }

    };
    timer.start();

}
}
```

Try above. and to understand clearly what you are doing read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*
    final Handler hnd = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) 
        {
            Bundle b = msg.getData();

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(b.getString("mymessage"));
        };
    };*/

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // Implement Runnable Interface to override method run();



        // Create A thread from runnable and start it....

        Thread th = new Thread(new Demo());
        th.start();

        }
    });
}

class Demo implements Runnable
{
    public void run() {

        /*
        Message msg = hnd.obtainMessage();

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("mymessage", "Button Pressed From Thread");

        msg.setData(data);
        hnd.sendMessage(msg);
        */
        tv.setText("showed");
    }
}
```

}